# Quick Action predefined field value default is overriding user input

Tags: quickaction

I've set up a quick action on the Account page to create Opportunities, and I've used Predefined Field Values to set some of the field defaults, but left those fields on the Action layout so that the user can change them before saving. However in some cases, even when the user changes the value of the field in the Action layout input, the predefined default value is what gets saved. I'm seeing this particularly when using `Account.BillingStreet` and `Account.ShippingStreet` as the predefined default value for custom Opportunity text fields.

According to [this documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values_notes.htm&type=5):

> If you set a predefined value for a field and leave it on the action layout, that value displays as the default value for the field.

So what I'm attempting to do seems like it should work and allow users to change the field value before saving.

Has anyone else run into or solved this issue? Or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: what field type are you noticing this for? I've run into this with lookup fields and this [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Hh6FQAS) was created

Comment: The cases I'm seeing involve copying account Address fields (e.g. BillingStreet) over to custom Opportunity text fields.